# How to make it clear to users, that they can write on our platform?

Tags: gui-design

I have build a publishing platform where users can write. I have the problem, that for "logged out" users it doesn't get clear, that they can write on eese (http://eese.com)

Here are some screenshots:

Screenshot 1: Landing page for logged out users
[image]

Screenshot 2:No headerbar - when the user scrolls the buttons get smaller

[image]
Screenshot 3: Open sidebar (menu)

[image]
Screenshot 4: Logged in users (in this case me). When you click the top right button you can create a story.

[image]

My metrics tells me, that users don't understand, that they can write on eese - obviously because there is no sign that u can do so.

How can i achieve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions to try,

1) change the wording "new" to the wording you use in your question.  E.g "write on ease", or "write an article".

2) try some highlighting techniques, maybe a subtle bit of animation, transition or some other such "look at me" technique (colour, size, position).  You could make this personal, even if they are anonymous.  E.g only do it if they haven't logged in before or submitted anything.  Probably have to look into if you can achieve this with some type of state, e.g local storage or cookie - cookies are probably worth trying to avoid if possible.

It is possible I have missed the point of the "new" button.  If I have and actually you do need to be logged in to create a story, but you want anonymous people to know this.  Do pretty much the same as above, but when they click to create a new story - politely ask for their details (login / register). I.e offer the same experience regardless of being logged in or not, and only make people login / register when they need to.

Comment: Very interesting. This gave me new insight :)
You thought, that on the "New" button you can create a new story. Actually the "New" button sorts the stream to the "Newest" stories. So maybe it should be renamed to "Newest"? This would make it more distinct.

Also for logged in users (see last picture) the "Create a new story" button is the top right button (pen). For logged out users we have no idea where to show this button because there are already two buttons ("login" and "register").

Comment: I've ammended my answer. Maybe try putting a create story action pride of place next to newest and only ask to log in / register after they choose it.

Comment: Do you think, that users understand that on the one hand they can sort a stream and on the other hand create a story?

If so - could be something worth considering!

Comment: Maybe, a good way to test it is to conduct a usability test. Either way, I would make sure the create action is always available, regardless of being logged in, so users know they can do it.